# What is the logic of "#ifdef" lines in the embedded if condition?

Tags: c, embedded

In the code below I have an push button example of efr32fg14 evalution board.

They use the `#ifdef` command which checks if the `BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT` variable is defined.

`BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT` is the port number neccesary for the command.
What if the logic of using `#ifdef` in the code below?

```
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "bsp.h"

// Push-buttons are active-low
#define PB_PRESSED (1)

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief GPIO initialization
 *****************************************************************************/
void initGPIO(void) 
{
  // Enable GPIO clock
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);

  // Configure PB0 and PB1 as input
  GPIO_PinModeSet(BSP_GPIO_PB0_PORT, BSP_GPIO_PB0_PIN, gpioModeInput, 0);
  GPIO_PinModeSet(BSP_GPIO_PB1_PORT, BSP_GPIO_PB1_PIN, gpioModeInput, 0);

  // Configure LED0 and LED1 as output
  GPIO_PinModeSet(BSP_GPIO_LED0_PORT, BSP_GPIO_LED0_PIN, gpioModePushPull, 0);
#ifdef BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT
  GPIO_PinModeSet(BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT, BSP_GPIO_LED1_PIN, gpioModePushPull, 0);
#endif
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief  Main function
 *****************************************************************************/
int main(void) 
{
  // Chip errata
  CHIP_Init();

  // Initializations
  initGPIO();

  while (1) 
  {
    // Set the state of LED0
    if (GPIO_PinInGet(BSP_GPIO_PB0_PORT, BSP_GPIO_PB0_PIN) == PB_PRESSED)
    {
      // LED0 On
      GPIO_PinOutSet(BSP_GPIO_LED0_PORT, BSP_GPIO_LED0_PIN);
    }
    else
    {
      // LED0 Off
      GPIO_PinOutClear(BSP_GPIO_LED0_PORT, BSP_GPIO_LED0_PIN);
    }

#ifdef BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT
    // Set the state of LED1
    if (GPIO_PinInGet(BSP_GPIO_PB1_PORT, BSP_GPIO_PB1_PIN) == PB_PRESSED)
    {
      // LED1 On
      GPIO_PinOutSet(BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT, BSP_GPIO_LED1_PIN);
    }
    else
    {
      // LED1 Off
      GPIO_PinOutClear(BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT, BSP_GPIO_LED1_PIN);
    }
#endif
  }
}
```

I have tried to look for the `#ifdef` definition to see the logic of this command in the code.

Comment: Lets the code compile if that macro isn't defined

Comment: The logic is to use the additional LED and switch if they exist and connected to `BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT` and `BSP_GPIO_PB1_PORT` respectively (which would be indicated by the definition of the symbol `BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT`)

Comment: `#ifdef` is parsed by the preprocessor (before the actual compilation starts). If the identifier `BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT` is defined when it reaches `#ifdef BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT` ... `#endif` the code between `#ifdef` and `#endif` will be a part of the program that will be compiled. If the identifier is _not_ defined, the code between `#ifdef` and `#endif` will be removed before compilation starts.

Comment: BTW: The preprocessor token is `ifdef` not `IFDEF`. If you want to emphasize a code token you can enclose the token with the ´ character.

Comment: Making backticks as inline code here is tricky: `\`` (just checking if that works - yes, backtick, backslash, backtick backtick) :-)

Comment: It is to compile only the code which is needed. If `BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT` is not defined, the code inside the #ifdef would not compile at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#ifdef` is a pre-processor directive (rather then a "*command*"), and is used for *conditional compilation*.

If the condition (in this case `defined BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT`) is false, the code between the condition and the corresponding `#endif` is removed from the compilation so that no code is generated for that section of source.

In this case the "logic" appears to be to conditionally build code that supports either one or two LEDs.  That is code related to `LED0` is *always* included,  and that for `LED1` is excluded unless `BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT`.

So to support `LED1`, you might either have a header that has (for example):

```
#define BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT gpioPortA
```

or you might use a command line swithc such as `-D BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT=gpioPortA` in GCC, CLANG and many other compilers.  Note that `defined`/`!defined` are Boolean states, the macro need not itself have a value, but here it is actually the port identifier for the GPIO.

Note that there is a corresponding `#ifndef` (if-not-defined), and both can have a `#else` section and zero or more `#elif` (else-if) sections.

`#ifdef`/`#ifndef` are however rather inflexible.  In C89 the more useful `defined` operator was added so that you can use `#if` and more complex expressions such as:

```
#if defined BSP_GPIO_LED1_PORT && defined BSP_GPIO_LED1_PIN
```

`#if` expressions allow Boolean expressions to control conditional compilation, rather then just `defined`/`!defined`.  `#ifdef` has been largely redundant since C89, but it seems to not be going away.